# Does there exist a symmetric tridiagonal matrix with zero determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I will like to know whether there exists a symmetric tridiagonal matrix with zero determinant? I will refer the definition of a tridiagonal matrix to the one found in Wikipedia:

"A tridiagonal matrix is a matrix that has nonzero elements only on the main diagonal, the first diagonal below this, and the first diagonal above the main diagonal.".

If yes, kindly provide an example. If not, please illustrate the proof or idea.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trivial example is
$$
\pmatrix{0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0}.
$$
Or you could consider:
$$
\pmatrix{1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1} \quad\text{or} \quad\pmatrix{1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1}.
$$
Otherwise if you only want non-zero entries of the diagonals, then how about
$$
\pmatrix{1 & a & 0 \\ a & 1 & a \\ 0 & a & 1}
$$
where $a = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Since you ask, I don't know if this might work, but try to consider
$$
\pmatrix{1 & a & 0 & 0\\ a & 1 & a & 0\\ 0 & a & 1& a \\ 0 & 0 & a & 1}
$$
and find the determinant of this matrix. This will be an expression in $a$. Can this ever equal zero? If this doesn't work, maybe this will give you an idea to something that would.

Comment: Hi. Your 3X3 matrix does not fulfill the definition by Wikipedia.

Comment: @Novice: Why not?

Comment: Your off diagonals should have non-zero entries. So the only zero entries in your matrix should be at the (1,3) and (3,1) position.

Comment: The zero matrix is also a symmetric tridiagonal matrix. The definition only requires the other elements to be zero, which are not on the three diagonals.

Comment: @Novice: From the way your definition is written, it sounds like the only non-zero  elements are allowed to be on one of the diagonals. It doesn't sound like they actually have to be non-zero...

Comment: Yes. Afterall it is a special case. If we follow the definition from the Wikipedia strictly, then it is not tridiagonal anymore.

Comment: @Thomas: right, so you could have taken the zero matrix.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: True ...

Comment: @Thomas: After reading the definition again, your argument makes sense: the only place for non-zero entries are on the diagonal and the two off diagonals. That does not mean that the those entries cannot be zero-valued.

Comment: @Novice: I think I found the example that you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you. That is a very nice example. I think this has also answered my another question regarding QR algorithm of symmetric tridiagonal matrices. Thanks alot. :)

Comment: @Thomas: Hi I will like to know, do you have any 4X4 nontrivial cases?

Comment: @Novice: Try to consider a $4\times 4$ matrix of the same form as the $3\times 3$ case above. Take the determinant and see if you can find a value of $a$ such that the determinant is zero. That might work.

Comment: @Novice: The Wikipedia definition is OK. It means that if $a_{ij}$ is nonzero then $a_{ij}$ lies on one of the respective diagonals. Note that a square zero matrix is: diagonal, tridiagonal, upper/lower triangular, Toeplitz, etc. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested in a symmetric tridiagonal matrix whose entries on the three diagonals are all nonzero, here's a way to obtain lots of $n \times n$ examples where the determinant is zero.    Let $L_k$ be the determinant of the matrix
formed by the first $k$ rows and columns of the tridiagonal symmetric $A = (a_{ij})$.
Then $L_k = L_{k-1} a_{k,k} - L_{k-2} a_{k-1,k}^2$ for $k \ge 3$.  If $L_{n-1}$ and $L_{n-2}$ and $a_{n-1,n}$ are all nonzero (which is true "generically"), you can take $a_{n,n} = L_{k-2} a_{k-1,k}^2/L_{k-1}$ to get your example.

Thus for a $4 \times 4$ example, I randomly chose the entries other than the bottom right as
$$ \pmatrix{2 & -1 & 0 & 0\cr -1 & 2 & -1 & 0\cr 0 & -1 & 1 & 1\cr 0 & 0 & 1 & a_{44}\cr}$$
and found that the determinant was $0$ for $a_{44} = 3$.